# Access values of array within array within object

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have an object

```
{
  'Bob Joerson': [
    [ 'Tuesday March 31, 2020', '07:58:12.0' ],
    [ 'Wednesday April 1, 2020', '11:00:03.7' ]
  ],
  'Joe Bobberson': [
    [ 'Tuesday March 31, 2020', '07:58:12.0' ],
    [ 'Wednesday April 1, 2020', '11:00:03.7' ]
  ]
}
```

How would I access the information within the array within the array?

I have tried:

```
<% for(var key in timesheets){ %>
    <% if(timesheets.hasOwnProperty(key)){ %>
    <% a = 0 %>
<table id="timesheetTable" class='table-primary table-bordered table' style='border-spacing: 10px;'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" id="name"> <%= key %> </td>
        <% for(var value in key){ %>
            <td> <%= value %> </td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
    <% a++ %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

But value just outputs the string index for the name stored in key.

When I try

```
<h1>Timesheet for dates</h1> 

<% for(var key in timesheets){ %>
    <% if(timesheets.hasOwnProperty(key)){ %>
    <% a = 0 %>
<table id="timesheetTable" class='table-primary table-bordered table' style='border-spacing: 10px;'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" id="name"> <%= key %> </td>
        <% for(i = 0; i < key.length; i++){ %>
            <td> <%= key %> </td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
    <% a++ %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

It just outputs the names over and over again in a table.

Comment: `key` is the key from your object, but you need the array, so use `timesheets[key]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% for(var key in timesheets){ %>
    <% if(timesheets.hasOwnProperty(key)){ %>
    <% a = 0 %>
<table id="timesheetTable" class='table-primary table-bordered table' style='border-spacing: 10px;'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" id="name"> <%= key %> </td>
        <% for(var value of timesheets[key]){ %>
            <td> <%= value[0] %><%= value[1] %> </td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
    <% a++ %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Note that `key` is each `key` of `timesheets` so `timesheets[key]` will be the value(array of arrays) of that key.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
        <% for(var entry of timesheets[key]){ %>
            <td> Date: <%= entry[0] %> </td>
            <td> Time: <%= entry[1] %> </td>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: the inner loop should be `for...of` not `for...in`.